# Google Script parsing JSON - what would be the path for the following?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am writing a script in which will download data from the twitter api into Google Sheets via a script.

The json file from twitter that has a strange path, according to a path analyser, to get the name, it is: [0].trends[k].name

Everything seem to be working apart from the last step when it tries to parse the data: `Trending.getRange(1,1,1,1).setValue(response_json.[0].trends[0].name);`

and I would get the following error message: **Missing name after . operator. (line 38, file "Code")**

Anyone got any ideas how I can parse this?

The JSON file is below:

```
[
    {
        "trends": [
            {
                "name": "#MakeLifeBetterIn3Words",
                "query": "%23MakeLifeBetterIn3Words",
                "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23MakeLifeBetterIn3Words",
                "promoted_content": null
            },
            {
                "name": "#ThingsJesusNeverSaid",
                "query": "%23ThingsJesusNeverSaid",
                "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23ThingsJesusNeverSaid",
                "promoted_content": null
            },
            {
                "name": "#askjack",
                "query": "%23askjack",
                "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23askjack",
                "promoted_content": null
            },
            {
                "name": "#charitytuesday",
                "query": "%23charitytuesday",
                "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23charitytuesday",
                "promoted_content": null
            },
            {
                "name": "#TravelTuesday",
                "query": "%23TravelTuesday",
                "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23TravelTuesday",
                "promoted_content": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Flight of the Conchords",
                "query": "%22Flight+of+the+Conchords%22",
                "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Flight+of+the+Conchords%22",
                "promoted_content": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Battle of Britain",
                "query": "%22Battle+of+Britain%22",
                "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Battle+of+Britain%22",
                "promoted_content": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Carol Kirkwood",
                "query": "%22Carol+Kirkwood%22",
                "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Carol+Kirkwood%22",
                "promoted_content": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Longannet",
                "query": "Longannet",
                "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=Longannet",
                "promoted_content": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Chris Rogers",
                "query": "%22Chris+Rogers%22",
                "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Chris+Rogers%22",
                "promoted_content": null
            }
        ],
        "as_of": "2015-08-18T11:16:11Z",
        "created_at": "2015-08-18T11:11:13Z",
        "locations": [
            {
                "name": "London",
                "woeid": 44418
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in here:

```
response_json.[0].trends[0].name
//           ^
```

Replace that with:

```
response_json[0].trends[0].name
```

Don't use a dot `.` before a bracket.

Comment: Thank you for helping a total novice! :)